# How to add expire header in nginx?

Tags: nginx, magento-1.9, google-pagespeed, expires-header

We have added expire header in /etc/nginx/site-available/default, but not reflecting in gtmatrix/google speed, we also check with curl website.

Please check our code below,

```
server {

root /var/www/html;

location / {

index index.php index.html;
try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
}
location /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {

if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite / /index.php last;
            }

include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
# With php7.0-cgi alone:
#fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
# With php7.0-fpm:
        fastcgi_read_timeout 20000;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit = -1";
}

    location ~* .(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with an additional backslash?

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|woff|woff2|svg)$ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma "public";
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

Also, you may want to split the block in order to use *gzip off* when it makes sense.

Best regards,